# Event Space Proofs

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

This is a problem from a Schaum's outline (I am self studying) and this is the solution.

I came up with an alternative proof (sorry I don't know how to add the intersection and union symbols.

If A is in F and B is in F, then by one of the properties of the event space, the union of A and B is in F. And since the intersection is contained in the union, i.e: the intersection is a subset of a union, then it follows that the intersection of A and B is also in F.

I prove the other result A\B similarly. Since B is in F, B' (complement of B) is also in F. and due to event spaces being closed under union: the union of A and B' is also in F. And I use the same technique as previous (intersection is subset of the union) to show that A intersect B' is in F.

Is my proof method correct?

Comment: I don't think it's always true that every subset of an event is itself an event. Is that one of the properties of events that is given somewhere in the book? If it is, then you don't need to mention the union – just note that $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for advice on typesetting math symbols here.

Comment: The properties of event spaces (stated in the book) said that unions of all events are in the even space. (if $A_i \in F$ then for $i \geq 1, \cup A_i \in F$) And I made the leap to say that if the union is in the event space, then the intersection is too. That part is not mentioned. Do I have to prove that? I thought it followed that if the intersection is in the union, which itself is in the event space then the intersection is too. 

$ A \cap B \subset A \cup B$  and $ A \cup B \in F$ then $A \cap B \in F$

Comment: $A\cup B \in \mathcal F$ does not imply $A\cap B \in \mathcal F$

Comment: @STRICKLAND_7 No, it definitely does not follow that if a set is a member of a collection of sets, then somehow every subset is a member of that collection.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I shall investigate why $A \cup B \in F$ does not imply $A \cap B \in F$

Comment: @Andrew I am having trouble proving your statement. Because I know in this case that the intersection is in $F$. How do I prove your statement?

Because in this case, $A \cap B$ is in fact in $F$ but how do I show that this is not simply due to the fact that $A \cup B \in F$?

Comment: You need to assume $A \in \mathcal F$ but $B\notin \mathcal F$. In that case, if $A\subset B$, then $A\cup B = B\notin \mathcal F$, whereas $A\cap B = A \in \mathcal F$

Comment: @Andrew thank you - that helps generally. However, in my original question post, it is known that $B \in \mathcal F$. So can I then say my original claim?

Comment: In your original question, it is known that both $A\in \mathcal F$ and $B\in \mathcal F$. By the way, you need to type "\mathcal F" as opposed to typing "F"

Comment: Thank you for the typesetting tip. My question remains, if $A \in \mathcal F$ and $B \in \mathcal F$ then is my original method of proof, valid?